# When implementing an interface in Generic, why it is not must implement the methods

Tags: c#, generics

When implementing an interface in Generic, why it is not must implement the methods

```
public interface IMyTest<T>
{
    T Add(T i, T j);
}

public class MyContainer<T> where T : IComparable<T>, IMyTest<T> 
{

}
```

Answer (score 14):

You're not implementing the interface. You're saying that the type argument supplied for the type parameter `T` must *itself* implement the interface. That's what the `where T` part means - it's specifying *constraints* on `T`.

This means that in your `MyContainer` class you can use the members of the interface:

```
public class MyContainer<T> where T : IComparable<T>, IMyTest<T> 
{
    public T SumBiggestAndSmallest(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var ordered = items.OrderBy(x => x)
                           .ToList();
        return ordered.First().Add(ordered.First(), ordered.Last());
    }
}
```

(It's unclear why your `Add` method *takes* two `T` values, as well as being an instance method, but that's a different matter.)

Without the constraints on `T`, you wouldn't have an `Add` method to call.